# Multivalued Combo Box in a Form

Tags: ms-access-2013

First, I tried to create a multivalued combo box in a form but the Lookup Wizard didn't give me the option like it does in a Table.

So...then I created exactly what I wanted in the field in the table. I know how to display the correct values you want using column bound, column width, etc.

I thought I could create a text box in the form and bound it to the appropriate field in the table. But the result I get is the ID number Access assigned to each record...not the descriptive value I actually want. How do I get the descriptive field (not the ID) to display in my form?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combobox.

`ControlSource` = *field name*

`ColumnCount` = 2

`CoulmnWidths` = 0cm